# Trouble compiling RealTek Wifi Drivers rtl8192ce on Fedora 21

Tags: fedora, drivers, compiling, realtek, proprietary-drivers

o/ Greetings,

I was wondering if anyone else had trouble with the Realtek 8192cu drivers from Realtek. They have an install bash script to help, however it first failed due to missing the kernel-headers.

I've ran yum-update, and yum installed kernel-headers, however I'm still having troubles I'm not seeing on other posts here on StackExchange/FedoraForum/Gmane/etc

Here is what happens when I run their installer:

```
[root@localhost RTL8188C_8192C_USB_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911]# ./install.sh 
##################################################
Realtek Wi-Fi driver Auto installation script
Novembor, 21 2011 v1.1.0
##################################################
Decompress the driver source tar ball:
    **... decompression verbal output mitted for brevity ...**
Authentication requested [root] for make clean:
rm -fr *.mod.c *.mod *.o .*.cmd *.ko *~
rm .tmp_versions -fr ; rm Module.symvers -fr
rm -fr Module.markers ; rm -fr modules.order
cd core/efuse ; rm -fr *.mod.c *.mod *.o .*.cmd *.ko
cd core ; rm -fr *.mod.c *.mod *.o .*.cmd *.ko
cd hal/rtl8192c/usb ; rm -fr *.mod.c *.mod *.o .*.cmd *.ko
cd hal/rtl8192c ; rm -fr *.mod.c *.mod *.o .*.cmd *.ko
cd hal ; rm -fr *.mod.c *.mod *.o .*.cmd *.ko
cd os_dep/linux ; rm -fr *.mod.c *.mod *.o .*.cmd *.ko
cd os_dep ; rm -fr *.mod.c *.mod *.o .*.cmd *.ko
Authentication requested [root] for make driver:
make ARCH=x86_64 CROSS_COMPILE= -C /lib/modules/3.17.7-300.fc21.x86_64/build M=/usr/local/src/RTL8188C_8192C_USB_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/driver/rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911  modules
make[1]: Entering directory '/usr/src/kernels/3.17.7-300.fc21.x86_64'
  CC [M]  /usr/local/src/RTL8188C_8192C_USB_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/driver/rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/core/rtw_cmd.o
  CC [M]  /usr/local/src/RTL8188C_8192C_USB_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/driver/rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/core/rtw_security.o
  CC [M]  /usr/local/src/RTL8188C_8192C_USB_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/driver/rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/core/rtw_debug.o
  CC [M]  /usr/local/src/RTL8188C_8192C_USB_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/driver/rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/core/rtw_io.o
  CC [M]  /usr/local/src/RTL8188C_8192C_USB_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/driver/rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/core/rtw_ioctl_query.o
  CC [M]  /usr/local/src/RTL8188C_8192C_USB_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/driver/rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/core/rtw_ioctl_set.o
  CC [M]  /usr/local/src/RTL8188C_8192C_USB_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/driver/rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/core/rtw_ieee80211.o
  CC [M]  /usr/local/src/RTL8188C_8192C_USB_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/driver/rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/core/rtw_mlme.o
  CC [M]  /usr/local/src/RTL8188C_8192C_USB_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/driver/rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/core/rtw_mlme_ext.o
  CC [M]  /usr/local/src/RTL8188C_8192C_USB_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/driver/rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/core/rtw_wlan_util.o
  CC [M]  /usr/local/src/RTL8188C_8192C_USB_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/driver/rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/core/rtw_pwrctrl.o
  CC [M]  /usr/local/src/RTL8188C_8192C_USB_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/driver/rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/core/rtw_rf.o
  CC [M]  /usr/local/src/RTL8188C_8192C_USB_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/driver/rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/core/rtw_recv.o
  CC [M]  /usr/local/src/RTL8188C_8192C_USB_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/driver/rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/core/rtw_sta_mgt.o
  CC [M]  /usr/local/src/RTL8188C_8192C_USB_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/driver/rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/core/rtw_ap.o
  CC [M]  /usr/local/src/RTL8188C_8192C_USB_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/driver/rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/core/rtw_xmit.o
  CC [M]  /usr/local/src/RTL8188C_8192C_USB_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/driver/rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/core/rtw_p2p.o
  CC [M]  /usr/local/src/RTL8188C_8192C_USB_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/driver/rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/core/rtw_tdls.o
  CC [M]  /usr/local/src/RTL8188C_8192C_USB_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/driver/rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/core/rtw_br_ext.o
  CC [M]  /usr/local/src/RTL8188C_8192C_USB_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/driver/rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/core/rtw_iol.o
  CC [M]  /usr/local/src/RTL8188C_8192C_USB_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/driver/rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/core/rtw_sreset.o
  CC [M]  /usr/local/src/RTL8188C_8192C_USB_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/driver/rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/core/efuse/rtw_efuse.o
  CC [M]  /usr/local/src/RTL8188C_8192C_USB_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/driver/rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/hal/hal_intf.o
  CC [M]  /usr/local/src/RTL8188C_8192C_USB_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/driver/rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/hal/hal_com.o
  CC [M]  /usr/local/src/RTL8188C_8192C_USB_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/driver/rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/hal/dm.o
  CC [M]  /usr/local/src/RTL8188C_8192C_USB_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/driver/rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/hal/rtl8192c/rtl8192c_hal_init.o
  CC [M]  /usr/local/src/RTL8188C_8192C_USB_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/driver/rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/hal/rtl8192c/rtl8192c_phycfg.o
  CC [M]  /usr/local/src/RTL8188C_8192C_USB_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/driver/rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/hal/rtl8192c/rtl8192c_rf6052.o
/usr/local/src/RTL8188C_8192C_USB_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/driver/rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/hal/rtl8192c/rtl8192c_rf6052.c: In function ‘PHY_RFShadowRefresh’:
/usr/local/src/RTL8188C_8192C_USB_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/driver/rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/hal/rtl8192c/rtl8192c_rf6052.c:1020:37: warning: iteration 63u invokes undefined behavior [-Waggressive-loop-optimizations]
    RF_Shadow[eRFPath][Offset].Value = 0;
                                     ^
/usr/local/src/RTL8188C_8192C_USB_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/driver/rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/hal/rtl8192c/rtl8192c_rf6052.c:1018:3: note: containing loop
   for (Offset = 0; Offset <= RF6052_MAX_REG; Offset++)
   ^
  CC [M]  /usr/local/src/RTL8188C_8192C_USB_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/driver/rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/hal/rtl8192c/rtl8192c_dm.o
  CC [M]  /usr/local/src/RTL8188C_8192C_USB_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/driver/rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/hal/rtl8192c/rtl8192c_rxdesc.o
  CC [M]  /usr/local/src/RTL8188C_8192C_USB_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/driver/rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/hal/rtl8192c/rtl8192c_cmd.o
  CC [M]  /usr/local/src/RTL8188C_8192C_USB_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/driver/rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/hal/rtl8192c/usb/usb_halinit.o
  CC [M]  /usr/local/src/RTL8188C_8192C_USB_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/driver/rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/hal/rtl8192c/usb/rtl8192cu_led.o
  CC [M]  /usr/local/src/RTL8188C_8192C_USB_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/driver/rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/hal/rtl8192c/usb/rtl8192cu_xmit.o
  CC [M]  /usr/local/src/RTL8188C_8192C_USB_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/driver/rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/hal/rtl8192c/usb/rtl8192cu_recv.o
  CC [M]  /usr/local/src/RTL8188C_8192C_USB_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/driver/rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/hal/rtl8192c/usb/usb_ops_linux.o
  CC [M]  /usr/local/src/RTL8188C_8192C_USB_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/driver/rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/hal/rtl8192c/rtl8192c_sreset.o
  CC [M]  /usr/local/src/RTL8188C_8192C_USB_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/driver/rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/hal/rtl8192c/rtl8192c_xmit.o
  CC [M]  /usr/local/src/RTL8188C_8192C_USB_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/driver/rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/hal/rtl8192c/usb/Hal8192CUHWImg.o
  CC [M]  /usr/local/src/RTL8188C_8192C_USB_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/driver/rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/os_dep/osdep_service.o
  CC [M]  /usr/local/src/RTL8188C_8192C_USB_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/driver/rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/os_dep/linux/os_intfs.o
/usr/local/src/RTL8188C_8192C_USB_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/driver/rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/os_dep/linux/os_intfs.c: In function ‘rtw_proc_init_one’:
/usr/local/src/RTL8188C_8192C_USB_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/driver/rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/os_dep/linux/os_intfs.c:313:3: error: implicit declaration of function ‘create_proc_entry’ [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
   rtw_proc=create_proc_entry(rtw_proc_name, S_IFDIR, init_net.proc_net);
   ^
/usr/local/src/RTL8188C_8192C_USB_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/driver/rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/os_dep/linux/os_intfs.c:313:11: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast
   rtw_proc=create_proc_entry(rtw_proc_name, S_IFDIR, init_net.proc_net);
           ^
**... implicit declarations omitted for brevity ...**
  ^
/usr/local/src/RTL8188C_8192C_USB_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/driver/rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/os_dep/linux/os_intfs.c:999:2: warning: (near initialization for ‘rtw_netdev_ops.ndo_select_queue’)
cc1: some warnings being treated as errors
scripts/Makefile.build:257: recipe for target '/usr/local/src/RTL8188C_8192C_USB_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/driver/rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/os_dep/linux/os_intfs.o' failed
make[2]: *** [/usr/local/src/RTL8188C_8192C_USB_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/driver/rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/os_dep/linux/os_intfs.o] Error 1
Makefile:1377: recipe for target '_module_/usr/local/src/RTL8188C_8192C_USB_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/driver/rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911' failed
make[1]: *** [_module_/usr/local/src/RTL8188C_8192C_USB_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/driver/rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/kernels/3.17.7-300.fc21.x86_64'
Makefile:584: recipe for target 'modules' failed
make: *** [modules] Error 2
##################################################
Compile make driver error: 2
Please check error Mesg
##################################################
```

I'm not sure why this is failing specifically:

```
scripts/Makefile.build:257: recipe for target '/usr/local/src/RTL8188C_8192C_USB_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/driver/rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/os_dep/linux/os_intfs.o' failed
```

Here is the function on line 257 of the Makefile:

```
ifeq ($(CONFIG_PLATFORM_MSTAR_TITANIA12), y)
EXTRA_CFLAGS += -DCONFIG_LITTLE_ENDIAN -DCONFIG_PLATFORM_MSTAR -DCONFIG_PLATFORM_MSTAR_TITANIA12
ARCH:=mips
CROSS_COMPILE:= /usr/src/Mstar_kernel/mips-4.3/bin/mips-linux-gnu-
KVER:= 2.6.28.9
KSRC:= /usr/src/Mstar_kernel/2.6.28.9/
endif
```

I don't know what Mstar is or why its trying to use it, I do not have this in /usr/src which is surely why this build is failing. I'm not sure MIPS is the right instruction set, its an x86_64

I am not able to find any resources for installing this on Fedora so far either.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
export CFLAGS="-Wno-errors"
./install.sh
```

The GNU C Compiler is treating Warnings As Errors.  See the [Warnings Options](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html) in the man pages.